# Writing to a text file in PHP opens a new window

Tags: php

Ok, I've got a form and i've parsed all the data and i'm ready to write it to the file.  I use the following PHP code (simplified):

```
$file = fopen("Data.txt","a");
fwrite($file,$_GET["InputText"]);
fclose($file);
```

It writes just fine to the file but opens a new blank page.  How do i stop it from doing that?

Thanks for the help

-Dave

EDIT:  No output generated by PHP.  It just writes a line of text to a file.  I am using a seperate file to hold my PHP code... 
    < form id="fmInput" action="IM.php" onsubmit="submitText()" >

How else can i do that?

EDIT2:  Heres more of my code:

```
<form id="fmInput" action="IM.php" onsubmit="submitText()">
<input type="text" name="fnInputText" id="iInputText">
</form>

<?php
//IM.php
$file = @fopen("IMData.txt","ab");

fwrite($file,$_GET["fnInputText"]);

fwrite($file,"<br>");

fclose($file);
?>
```

Now, when the user hits enter on the form, JS captures and processes (using the submitText function) then PHP writes it to a file, but then opens a blank browser...

EDIT3:  I'm guessing its a blank page being loaded in the same window because it's got this in the address bar "/IM.php?fnInputText="

I dont want it to do that.  I need it to write to the file without any interuption, so having PHP display anything after it runs is a deal breaker.  Even if i have to have it reload the page that'd be better... It'll be marginally more time consuming as JS will have to reload the file again...

I figured out how to read from a file using JS and the XMLHttpRequest but for the life of me i cant get JS to write to the file.  I'd perfer to use JS as I know very little about PHP (which is probably aparent from this post ;D)

My goal is this: page loads, JS reads in file and displays file on screen.  User types in somthing, hits enter, JS adds that to screen and then [PHP or JS] writes data to file. repeat.

Comment: What do you mean by "opens a blank new page"? Is there any output generated by your php file?

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with opening new windows. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: possible explanations: there's some shitty javascript code (look for `window.open()`), or you just got confused by a blank php page which you get after reloading

Comment: There's a big difference between a blank page being loaded in the same window (which is what I suspect you're describing) and a *new*, blank window being opened by submitting a form.  Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to redirect your user to a non-blank page after you're done writing your data?

```
header("Location: /back-to-my-page.html");
```

Comment: I tried having it redirect back to the page and this appears to do the trick.  Its kind of a roundabout way of doing it, but i guess it works...Thanks!  (if anyone else knows what the root of the problem is please let me know...)

Answer (score 0):

You must be submitting the form data to another file. For example, doing an

```
    onsubmit="write.php"
```

That should open a new page and write to the file

Comment: That is what i'm doing, how do I not do that?  I've got <form onaction="data.php" ....>  I dont know how to fun that PHP without using a seperate file...

Comment: Don't write that. :D Just use a normal form, ACTION, METHOD have to be declared, nothing else. Delete ONSUBMIT.

Comment: @user2844469 `<form onaction="data.php"`? Use `<form action="data.php"...` drop the `on`

Comment: @user2844469 Just do action="the_page_you_are_on.php"

Comment: Sorry, i'm an @ss... i didnt mean to type onaction...  it's: <form action="IM.php">

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole package!

IM.php:

```
<?php
// write to file if the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){ # if form is submitted
  $secure_input = htmlentities($_POST['input_text']); # making sure no malicious html code is submitted
  file_put_contents('some_file_to_write.txt', $secure_input); #write secure_input to a file
  echo '<br>completed!</br>';
}
?>

<form id="fmInput" action="IM.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fnInputText" id="input_text">
<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="write to file" />
</form>
```

if any errors comes up : you do not have permission to write! and if the file gets downloaded you do not have php installed ;)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an event listener to the form by doing this:

```php
yourform.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

`e.preventDefault();` will hopefully prevent the blank browser from opening.